# Do not have option to create QDialog type Project in Qt 5.8

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

The title says it all, I just don't have the option to create a dialog project. Earlier I did and I can't think of anything I've done with Qt in the time to disable the dialog creation.

Comment: You must create a project of type `Qt Widgets Application -> choose -> next -> next -> change QMainWindow to QDialog -> next -> finish`

Comment: Oh thanks. I feel really stupid